# Functional switch statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Say I have a switch statement that takes a variable myData between 1 and some larger value, i.e. 300.

Depending on the "status code" variable, the result is the text value of another variable. For example, if `myData == 1`, I want to return the a variable called `code1`. If `myData == 300`, I want to return the a variable called `code300`. Code1 and code300 variables store unrelated strings, i.e. "This is a summary", or "This is a note". Some psuedo-code below:

```
var myData = statusCode;

var code1 = "This is a summary";
var code300 = "This is a note";

switch(myData) {
    case statusCode:
        scriptletResult = returnCode("code", statusCode); // code1 if myData == 1
        break;          
    default:
        scriptletResult = code1;
}

function returnCode(code, statusCode) {
    return code + statusCode; // Returns a variable "code1" if statusCode == 1
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Are the `codeX` variables as-is, or can you move them into an object where the code is the key?

Comment: They are as-is, pre-defined.

Comment: What you're asking for is variable variables, which doesn't work in Javascript as such. The sane thing is to have an array or object mapping from key to value, so you can do a simple `codes[myData]`.

Comment: Right - the only way to do this as-is is to use `eval`, which is far from the safest solution.  `eval(code + statusCode)` is the (bad) quick-fix

Comment: You can totally have variable variables-- use `window[variableName]` (array syntax).

Comment: @Feathercrown That's assuming all the required `code` variables are globals though

Comment: @Jonasw -_- It's pretty much the only way it works, and others were saying it didn't, so any way is good (except eval :P). "Style" isn't really a consideration if you only have 1 good option. I guess you could do `function getVar(var){return window[var];}` or something....

Comment: @Scott True.... hmm. Idk then lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use a lookup map for that, instead of multiple variables:

```
var codes = {
    1: "This is a summary",
    300: "This is a note"
};
```

With that you can do

```
if (statusCode in codes) {
    scriptletResult = codes[statusCode];
} else {
    scriptletResult = codes[1];
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, but I believe OP says he cannot move the variables for some reason.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the closest to what I would want to accomplish. This doesn't change the fact somebody would have to write 300 "codes" strings, but it does reduce the number of switch statements required...

Comment: @Scott In that case, `var codes = {1: code1, 300: code300}` might be a solution. Or `eval` with a whitelist (-regex) of variable names in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myData=300;
var code1="This is a summary";
var code300=" this is a note";
var result=(function(){
switch(myData) {
case 1:
    return code1;        
case 300:
   return code300,
default:
    return "not defined";
}
})();

alert(result);
```

Perfect usecase for an IIFE + switch combo.

However best would be:

```
alert([code1,code2][myData]);
```

Comment: `['This is a summary', ...][myData] || 'not defined'`…

Comment: @deceze he wanted a *functional switch statement* . not saying that this is useful...

Comment: Whatever "functional switch statement" means exactly… :P

Answer (score 1):

@Bergi's answer is the best approach, but if you can't change the way your code-message combos are stored, and the variables are globals, you can use:

```
scriptletResult=window["code"+myData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourStatusCode = 300; //function get300();
var data = "MyData"; //function data();

function runner(){
    switch(data){
        case "MyData":
        myFunc();
        return "hola data we are looking for!";
        break;
        case "DataNumberTwo":
        return "this is data number 2";
        break;
        default:
        return "WOAH what data is this??";
        break;
    }

}

console.log(runner());
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functional switch statement that allows lambda pattern matching

```js
const switchF = (c, options, def) => {
  const choice = options.find(([key, ]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(key)) {
      return key.indexOf(c) >= 0;
    }
    if (typeof key === "function") {
      return key(c);
    }
    return key === c;
  });
  if (!choice) return def();
  const [, choiceVal] = choice;
  if (typeof choiceVal === "function") return choiceVal();
  if (typeof choiceVal === "string") {
    return switchF(choiceVal, options, def);
  }
  throw Error("switch F Failed!");
};
```

Example use:

```js
const switcher = (c) =>
  switchF(
    c,
    [
      ["foo", () => "Foo option"],
      ["bar", "foo"],
      [(v) => v > 3, () => 99],
    ],
    () => "DEFAULT"
  );

console.log(switcher("foo")); // returns 'Foo'
console.log(switcher("bar")); // returns 'Foo
console.log(switcher(4)); // returns '99'
console.log(switcher(2)); // returns 'DEFAULT'
console.log(switcher("zzz")); returns 'DEFAULT'
```