# Better (Functional) alternate to multiple switch cases in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

The Object Lookup method is very popular in JS and used as a better replacement for Switch-case statements e.g.

```
function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";

  switch(val) {
    case "alpha":
      result = "Adams";
      break;
    case "bravo":
      result = "Boston";
      break;
    case "charlie":
      result = "Chicago";
      break;
  }
  return result;
}


function phoneticLookup(val) {
  var result = "";

  var lookup = {
    "alpha": "Adams",
    "bravo": "Boston",
    "charlie": "Chicago",
  };

  result = lookup[val];
  return result;
}
```

But if the switch case is like the one below, as you can see multiple cases return the same result. How can we write it in a better way using `objects`, `map`, or any other way (not using `if-else`) in JS?

```
let continent = '';
switch (country) {
   case "China":
   case "India":
   case "Nepal": 
       continent = 'Asia';
       break;
   case "UK":
   case "France":
   case "Poland": 
       continent = 'Europe';
       break;
   case "Egypt":
   case "Zimbave":
   case "Somalia": 
       continent = 'Africa';
       break;
   default: 
       continent = 'Other'
       break;
}
```

Comment: there are 5 continents and around 200 countries in the world. It absolutely does not matter how you implement this lookup, because it will take a couple of milliseconds in any case. Nothing to optimize here, move along.

Comment: @gog that is just an example

Comment: example of what? It would be more useful to tell us about the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: What this tells you is that obtaining conditional branching through object property access is crap. Functional programming is not about avoiding conditional branching. It is about making effects explicit and things composable. So all you need to do is transforming your switch statement into an expression: `s => {switch(s) {...}}`

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Thank you for the explanation and clarifying the FP concept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not introducing any abstraction. You can probably make your *switch* functional by just hiding it within a function (no need to look at a function internals)...

The only advise on top of what you already have could be to using *`return`* rather than mutating a var and then breaking.

```js
const whichContinent = (country) => {
  switch (country) {
   case "China":
   case "India":
   case "Nepal": 
     return 'Asia';

   case "UK":
   case "France":
   case "Poland": 
     return 'Europe';

   case "Egypt":
   case "Zimbave":
   case "Somalia": 
     return 'Africa';

   default: 
     return 'Unknown'
  }
}

console.log(
  whichContinent('hogwarts'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. The [pattern matching propsal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching) is Stage 1 and may never make it into the standard. You could write a custom switch/match function as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67621725/5774952). For this specific case you actually could use an object lookup, just a little differently:

```
const continents = {
  "Africa": ["Egypt", "Ghana"], // etc
  "Asia": ["China", "Bhutan"], // etc
}

const assignContinent = (country) => {
  const possibleMatch = Object.entries(continents)
    .find((continent) => continent[1].includes(country))
  return possibleMatch ? possibleMatch[0] : "Other"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance I recommend defining a mapping with repetition of continent:

```js
countryToContinentMap = {
   China:   'Asia',
   India:   'Asia',
   Nepal:   'Asia',
   UK:      'Europe',
   France:  'Europe',
   Poland:  'Europe',
   Egypt:   'Africa',
   Zimbave: 'Africa',
   Somalia: 'Africa'
}

function getContinent(country) {
    return countryToContinentMap[country] || 'Other';
}

console.log('Nepal => ' + getContinent('Nepal'));
console.log('Xomur => ' + getContinent('Xomur'));
```

Output:

```
Nepal => Asia
Xomur => Other
```

To make it easier o define the mapping, you could do it as @Zac Anger did, then programmatically reverse the mapping once before use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your object lookup version, one of the simplest ways to achieve it, is to create an object with countries as values and continents as keys. Then dynamically create an object which will have continents as values and countries as keys.

```js
const continents = {
   "Asia": ["China", "India", "Nepal"],
   "Europe": ["UK", "France", "Poland"],
   "Africa": ["Egypt", "Zimbabwe", "Somalia"],
};

let countryContinent = {};

for(const [continent, countries] of Object.entries(continents)){
//Merge countryContinent with newly created object with countries as keys and for each key value equal to continent
   countryContinent = Object.assign(countryContinent, Object.fromEntries(countries.map(country =>[country, continent])));
}
```

Now as `countryContinent` object looks like this:

```js
{
  'China': 'Asia',
  'India': 'Asia',
  'Nepal': 'Asia',
  'UK': 'Europe',
  'France': 'Europe',
  'Poland': 'Europe',
  'Egypt': 'Africa',
  'Zimbabwe': 'Africa',
  'Somalia': 'Africa'
}
```

You can freely use your `phoneticLookup` function on it.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view, it's very unlikely you'll notice any performance gain/drop from swapping one approach with the other. There's nothing wrong with a switch statement but a map simply feels like a better fit to me:

- Why go over the `case` clauses one by one when you can hit the correct answer immediately?
- A map can be constructed and updated on demand, you can't dynamically build a `switch` statement.
- You can save a map into a file (JSON) and use it for other purposes (e.g. counting the number of countries per continent).

Perhaps what you're missing is a recipe to work with maps? This is what I usually do:

A curried lookup function you can use to build mapping functions:

```js
const lookup = m => k => m[k];

const continent = lookup({ Belgium: 'Europe'
                         , Japan:     'Asia'
                         , Kenya:   'Africa'});

continent('Japan');
//> 'Asia'
```

If I need to lookup *and* transform:

```js
const lookup = (pass, fail, m) => k => k in m ? pass(m[k], k) : fail(k);

const continent = lookup( (cont, country) => `${country} is in ${cont}`
                        , (country) => `Cannot locate ${country} on Earth :(`
                        , { Belgium: 'Europe'
                          , Japan:     'Asia'
                          , Kenya:   'Africa'});

continent('Japan');
//> 'Japan is in Asia'

continent('Neverland');
//> 'Cannot locate Neverland on Earth :('
```